# Scipt error in IOS firefox(IPhone device) - react app

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, firefox

I am getting **script error** in my react app on **IOS firefox**(iphone device).
I searched around the web, cause of this error is errors in external js library.

but I am not loading any external lib as of now in my app.
how to debug this script error, in all other browsers I dont get this error.

Firefox version : Daylight 30.0(3279) (recently downloaded)

Thanks in advance